# jQuery: how to make ajaxSend wait for another Ajax response before proceeding?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I'm using jQuery (v.3.0.0) and I need [ajaxSend()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxsend/) to check if a value is present in `localStorage`, to add it in the outgoing request headers.

If the value is not present in `localStorage`, `ajaxSend()` should get this value with another Ajax request and then send the original request with the correct value in the headers.

**This must be a global handler, that applies to all jQuery Ajax requests that are sent out.**

Let's make a code example.

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function (ev, req, opts) {
  // Before sending any jQuery Ajax request
  var original = req;
  if (localStorage.foo) {
    // If value "foo" is available, add it to the headers
    req.setRequestHeader('foo', localStorage.foo);
  } else {
    // Otherwise get it first, and add it to the headers
    $.get({url: '/foo', global: false})
      .done(function (data, textStatus, req) {
        // "foo" is received and added to the original request headers
        localStorage.foo = data;
        original.setRequestHeader('foo', data);
        // Now the original request is ready to be sent
      });
  }
});
```

When `foo` is not available, the problem with the code above is that obviously the original request is sent out before the value of `foo` is retrieved.

Is there any way to fix this and get it to work properly?

Thanks!!

Comment: Can't you add `async: false` to the second ajax call?

Comment: No, that would block everything in the meantime and is definitely not a good choice. Btw, it's also mentioned in the [`jQuery.ajax()` docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), check it out:
"Setting this option to false (and thus making the call no longer asynchronous) is strongly discouraged, as it can cause the browser to become unresponsive."

Comment: Well i'm sorry but you're trying to wrap one ajax call inside another ajax call and that's not going to work

Comment: Well, that's exactly what I'm trying to solve. If one finds a way control the queuing of Ajax calls then it can be solved.

Answer (score 3):

So far, this is the best solution that I could find. It's not perfect, and it does not exactly answer the original question, but it's a good workaround and gets very close to what I was trying to achieve.

The main difference is that instead of making the original request wait, it cancels it, it gets the desired value, and then it creates a new request with the same settings as the original one.

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function (ev, req, opts) {
  if (localStorage.foo) {
    // If value "foo" is available, add it to the headers
    req.setRequestHeader('foo', localStorage.foo);
  } else {
    // Otherwise cancel the original request, then get "foo",
    // and create a new request with the same settings as the original one
    req.abort();
    $.get({url: '/foo', global: false})
      .done(function (data, textStatus, req) {
        // "foo" is received
        localStorage.foo = data;
      })
      .then(function () {
        $.ajax(opts);
      });
  }
});
```

It works perfectly. If someone finds out a better solution that allows to directly use the original request I'll be happy to edit this answer and improve it.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you found or can suggest now any better approach?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the `beforeSend` option of `$.ajax`, you can return `false` from there if the value is present in localStorage in order to stop the request.

This will mean you always have to use the low-level `$.ajax` method, perhaps you could make your own set of wrappers for `$.get`, `$.post`, `$.getJSON` etc.

Comment: Thanks Matt! Could you be so kind to post a working code example of the approach you suggest? Cheers :)

Comment: Ended up doing it without beforeSend. You'll need to add the other wrappers, and it also means you need to always use the promise-style callbacks (ie `done`, `fail`, `always`, etc) instead of using parameter callbacks, plus probably some other things.

Comment: Hi Matt, I looked at your code, it doesn't seem to me though that this is handling all outgoing jQuery Ajax requests. I know how to write promises, or chain async events, although that's not my original question. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant about wrappers, you'd have to modify your code to use wrapper functions. It's not that big a deal, I've done it a few times. I can't think of any other way sorry.

Comment: Ok, I'll wait to see if someone elese comes up with a different solution, but in the meantime thanks for your help Matt!!  :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that does not need to abort the original request as in  Pensierinmusica's answer. Instead the send method of the xhr object of the original AJAX call is overridden, and the original send with arguments can then be invoked later when e.g. another AJAX request completes. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30263533

Comment: Just linking to other answers would make this comment look poor. I would advice adapting this anwer to the problem adding some actual code and linking the other answer as a reference.